# get single data from multiple data with jquery

Tags: arrays, jquery

i have table view like below
[image]

```
<table>
<tr><th>Username</th>
<th>Departemen</th><th>Created By</th><th>Created Date</th><th>Last Update By</th><th>Last Update Date</th><th>Aksi</th></tr>
<?php   
    $sql = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM tblMstUser where CompanyDeptID ='11' or CompanyDeptID ='12' order by LoginID";
    $tampil = mssql_query($sql) ;
    while($r=mssql_fetch_array($tampil)){
      echo "<tr><td>$r[LoginID]</td>
                <td>$r[LoginName]</td>
                <td>$r[CreatedBy]</td>
                <td>$r[CreatedDate]</td>
                <td>$r[LastUpdatedBy]</td>
                <td>$r[LastUpdatedDate]</td>

                <td>
                     <button id='edit' onclick=\"popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down', parent : this});\"'><image src='images/Edit.png'/>Edit</button> | 
                     <button id='delete'><image src='images/delete.png'/>Hapus</button>
                </td>
                </tr>";
      $no++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

my purpose when user click "edit" all of field in popup will filled by related data using LoginID as parameter in my sql. i use ms sql 2008 as mya database server.
my problem how i can get a single data from array "$r[LoginID]" using Jquery for each row.

Answer (score 0):

pass `LoginID` to the function as parameter along with button onClick, eg.

```
<button id='edit' onclick=\"popup_window_show('#sample', '$r[LoginID]' ,{ pos : 'tag-right-down', parent : this});\"'>
```

and fire ajax call with jQuery to a page, the page returns data related to LoginID and fill all editable fileds in the edit form.